# create or customize popunder such as UITextField corrector

Tags: iphone, ios, popup, uitextfield, spell-checking

Good day, tell me how to create or customize popunder such as UITextField corrector (see screenshot)
or can i made fully custom corrector spell-chek dictionary for predifinied only words(not for system dictionar).
Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vgsT.png

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far and explain better what you are stuck on. If you are looking for a tutorial then perhaps search for auto correct or auto complete UITextField on Google

Comment: updated comment see screenshot. Adam Richardson: i'm trying UITextChecker, UITextChecker added my words and include system words, i'm need only predifinied my words.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, you want a special filed for suggestions.
For the web purpose there is a great JQuery UI Component - [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), but i suppose you are looking for something similar for IOS, right?